# Is Java only way to write apps for Android?

Tags: android

I've searching the Internet for the answer but I can only find answers either that are too old, are confusing or people not answering the question but rather telling to learn Java.

My basic questions are:

1. Is Java the only way to write apps for Android?
2. This question will contradict #1. Since Adobe AIR can run in Android phones now, does that mean I can write in AS3 without Java or do I need to wrap the AIR app inside Java?
3. Are apps like Facebook for Android, Angry Birds and all those fancy games, made in Java only?
4. If #1==false && me==JAVA_HATER, what language or SDK do you guys recommend. This is my main question.

Answer (score 8):

1. It's the only Google-supported way.  There are others, for example Adobe Air; and, if you wanted to do some work to figure out linkage to the standard Android classes, you could copy and modify the Ant recipes in the SDK to work with any language targeting the JVM.
2. Air apps, as with any other platform, run in an Air virtual machine which runs on the target platform "natively".  (Which, for Android, means it was probably written in Java, compiled to JVM bytecode, then transcoded to Dalvik bytecode.)  Note that it *is* possible to write native (usually ARM) code and link it with a basic Java framework, although there are a number of limitations on such code.  I would imagine that the Appcelerator mentioned elsepage works by translating the Javascript to something else (there are several Javascript-to-Java translators).
3. Most Android applications are written in Java.  Some apps, especially those that say they won't run on versions of Android below 2.0, have native code libraries.  See #2.
4. Java works "out of the box".  With a little work, as I mentioned above (#1), you should be able to write code in any language that produces JVM bytecode and knows how to link to Java class libraries.  (I fully expect someone to provide Scala linkage. :)

Comment: And per http://www.codecommit.com/blog/java/interop-between-java-and-scala that just means someone needs to do some Ant recipe hacking and they're golden.

Comment: 1 is clearly wrong, given the [NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html) you mention yourself.  There are other examples, too, like [Scripting Layer for Android](http://www.googlelabs.com/show_details?app_key=agtnbGFiczIwLXd3d3IUCxIMTGFic0FwcE1vZGVsGKWdNgw).

Comment: Depends on your interpretation.  It's only recently that it became possible to do I/O from the NDK instead of having to call back into Java, for example, and even more recently that you could use the NDK to write entire applications.

Comment: Is Mono supported on android?

Answer (score 2):

Adobe Air for Android takes care of the integration for you - you don't have to write any Java to make it work. It's actually a straight-up AIR app and if the user of the device has Air for Android installed then your app will work, simple as that.

The native code (java) vs AIR debate has been raging for a long time - depending on the type of app you're making you COULD see gains from writing Java, since it's one less layer on the project. On the other hand, the difference is minimal if you're not animating a billion shapes or whatever - so in many cases AIR is just fine.

The other option that you have is to build your app using HTML/JavaScript and simply embed it into a Java or ObjC wrapper that compiles into a native app on Android/iPhone - many apps, especially the ones that are just user interfaces for some sort of data set, use this approach.

So, depending your use case you have lots of options! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try [appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/). You write in javascript, and somehow it translates it to a Android app.

Answer (score 0):

The [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html) provides:

A set of tools and build files used to generate native code libraries from C and C++ sources.